# Scala Futures and Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, scala, future

I am new to Scala and I'm trying to get an handle on futures and multithreading

I have a SingleThreaded version of a program that makes some calculations on a matrix

```
SingleThreadCalc {
  def run(matrix : Seq[Seq[Double]]) : Future[Seq[Seq[Double]] = Future{doMath(matrix)}
}
```

What i want now is to make a multithreaded version of it.
is it enought to just pass an ExecutionContext with a number of threads?

```
MultiThreadCalc {
  def run(matrix : Seq[Seq[Double]]) : Future[Seq[Seq[Double]] = 
Future{doMath(matrix)} (ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)))
```

Will this share the computation load between all the threads or is it not happening at all?

Comment: The short answer that i would give is "apparently so", but I think the best answer would come from running the thing and measuring.

Comment: I Think the first step for you if to break down your doMath into tasks that can be executer in parallel.

Comment: @jamborta right now it is a double for to iterate over the matrix's elements
i was thinking about refactoring to line processing
but can I control which thread ends up processing each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:

```
object MultiThreadCalc {
 def run(matrix : Seq[Seq[Double]]) : Future[Seq[Seq[Double]] = 
    Future{doMath(matrix)}(ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)))
}
```

The code above will, for every invocation of `run`, will allocate a new thread pool which will never be shut down, and it will be used to execute a single method `doMath` (so only 1 thread in that pool will be used).

Now, if you want to parallelize execution of `doMath` itself, then you'll need to modify ts definition to be parallelizable, possibly by making it take an `implicit ec: ExecutionContext` parameter and using that within its definition.

But if you instead want to be able to run many invocations of `doMath` in parallel then you can do the following:

```
object MultiThreadCalc {
  def run(matrix : Seq[Seq[Double]])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) : Future[Seq[Seq[Double]] = Future{doMath(matrix)}
}
```

And then create an ExecutionContext possibly `ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))` on the "outside" and use it whenever you want to execute logic on it.

Comment: I was suspecting that...
I'll refactor my doMath and then try to change the ExecutionContext so I can parallelize the execution